# New GHC feature - did I imagine it?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I swear I saw a new feature in a recent set of GHC release notes - but now I can find no reference to it. Am I delusional, or does this feature actually exist?

It was to do with loading incomplete modules. As best as I can remember, it allows you to turn off compilation errors due to undefined variables. (Naturally, at run-time this causes an exception to be thrown if you try to actually *use* the undefined variables for anything.) Does that sound familiar? Or is my mind making this up?

Comment: Are you thinking of http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DeferErrorsToRuntime

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Yes, I'm pretty sure that's what I'm remembering. http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/defer-type-errors.html

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson you should submit that as a proper answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for a compile time option, vs a language extension, of "[defer errors to runtime](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DeferErrorsToRuntime)".  That is, compile with `-fdefer-type-errors`.

Comment: For anyone without the patience to read the linked documentation, this feature doesn't actually let you omit variable definitions; it allows you to compile a module even if parts of it don't type-check. (Any attempt to utilise those parts obviously throws an exception...) It's useful if you're in the middle of editing a module and want to quickly try out the bit you've finished editing without having to fix the entire thing...